# Is it possible to make bend with google maps polyline?

Tags: polyline

I have a question, is it possible to make a bend in google maps polyline with the latitude and the longitude?
I want to paint lines over the railways and there are bends.

My question is: is this possible and is here a tutorial on the internet?

thanks in advance.